# Excise recent date from log file, output as motd

Tags: bash, grep, motd

For finding a date in a log file I've arrived at the following crude command:

```
grep Updated /var/log/socklog/xbps/current | tail -n 1 | grep -Eo ^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
```

That does what I need, which is to output the date of the last system upgrade I did on my Void machine: for example 2019-01-24. But it's a pretty cumbersome line and quite crude as well. I assume there must be a more elegant solution to extract the needed date from this file. Incidentally, the date is comprised by the first 10 characters of the line containing the text `grep`'d/`tail`'d for (the last, or most recent, occurrence in the file). Any suggestions for a more elegant solution?

This line, btw, is being used to produce a `motd` so that when I log into my system I'll see something like "last system upgrade 2019-01-24." So I created a script `/etc/motd.sh` with that line in it, which then gets called from /etc/profile. Am I going about making the information visible in the correct way? What might be some other alternatives for doing what I want?

The script `/etc/motd.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo last system upgrade $(grep Updated /var/log/socklog/xbps/current | tail -n 1 | grep -Eo ^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])
```

PS Here's a sample line from the log file, as requested:

```
2019-01-15T18:05:51.31699 user.notice: Jan 15 12:05:51 xbps-install: Installed `brotli-1.0.7_1' successfully (rootdir: /).
2019-01-15T18:05:51.35465 user.notice: Jan 15 12:05:51 xbps-install: Updated `xwininfo-1.1.4_2' successfully (rootdir: /).
```

Comment: I think it'd help answerers to see sample lines from the input file

Comment: I agree with Jeff, but also, if it works, it works. Without seeing the input file, it doesn't seem so inelegant to me.

Comment: The sample line doesn't have 'Updated' in it, is there more to the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use `awk`. Split fields at the `T` in the datestamp, look for `Updated`, and print the last occurrence.

```
awk -FT '/Updated/ {date=$1} END {print date}' /var/log/socklog/xbps/current
```

You can interpolate that directly, or take the slightly more readable approach

```
#!/bin/bash
#
updated=$(awk -FT '/Updated/ {date=$1} END {print date}' /var/log/socklog/xbps/current)
[[ -n "$updated" ]] && printf "Last system upgrade %s\n" "$updated"
```

Comment: This definitely looks more elegant than the multiple greps + tail that I came up with. Think I'll go ahead and mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the  date is first 10 characters, then you can use cut instead of the second grep

```
tail -n 1 | cut -c1-10
```

Comment: Yeah, this works too. But it doesn't do any streamlining--it still requires 2 pipes. Replaces one of the greps with cut.

Comment: Using pipes and a few simple operations might be more elegant than using no pipes an one convoluted command. It all depends on your circumstance. To me readability trumps brevity